# Mic on Macbook Pro not working properly

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, microphone

I don't often use my built in microphone (or any audio input) but today i need to use and it doesn't show any input. That is unless I tap the left speaker, then it does record the taps. But nothing else.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open up "System Preferences" then the Sound tab. Make sure "Internal Microphone" is selected, and that the input volume is turned up.

Comment: I done that already to no avail, and reset the Pram or something